# mysql phpadmin update table1 column after join with table2 where specific field name is searched for

Tags: mysql

This is my first post and I apologize that the title is mess.  If someone can suggest a better one, I'll update it accordingly.

My experience with sql is extremely small.  The few queries I've put together have come from the little knowledge I have from coding in high school and a lot of google searching.  Then I then splice things together and look like what I might need.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  Below is a query that I got working but I'm trying to expand on it to make it easier.

```
UPDATE `Database`.`products` 
SET `clearance` = 'Y', `products_order_date` = 'ENTER DATE HERE'
```

WHERE `products_id` IN (51604,51603,49209,49208,49207,45222,45220)

The part I'm trying to make easier on myself is having to enter every product ID for this particular update.  I would rather use LIKE %% instead of IN but there is not a column in 'products' that I can use.  However, there is a table called 'products_description' which also has a column called 'products_id'.  This table has a column called 'products_name'.  If I could search by products_name, it would make my work easier.

A crude example of what I need is

```
UPDATE `Database`.`products` 
SET `clearance` = 'Y', `products_order_date` = 'ENTER DATE HERE'
JOIN THE 2 TABLES SOMEHOW
WHERE `products_name` LIKE %WHATEVER%
```

I really hope this makes sense, if not please let me know.

Ideally, I would love to have the products_name column, which is currently in the products_description table, copied to the first table and have it match up with the products_id so then I wouldn't need to do this join thing.  But of course I do not know how to do that either.

Hope someone can assist.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
    `handbags_jnh`.`products` as p join `products_description` as pd on p.products_id = pd.products_id 
SET 
    clearance = 'Y', products_order_date = 'ENTER DATE HERE' 
WHERE 
    products_nam`e LIKE %WHATEVER%
```

Comment: the p and pd.  are those temps? or a shortcut so you don't have to type out the whole name each time?

Comment: just tried it.  it works amazingly.  thank you very much!

Comment: they are called alias name, its used to avoid ambiguity when using the column 'products_id' which is present in two tables.

Comment: sorry. didn't see that little gray check part.  thank you